# Zeros of Holomorphic (upper bound)

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm looking at old complex analysis exams and am stuck on the following.  Suppose f(z) is holomorphic on $D(0,2)$ and continuous on its closure.

Suppose the $|f(z)|\le 16$ on the closure of  $D(0,2)$ and is non-constant and |f(0)|=1.   Show $f$ cannot have more than 4 zeros in $D(0,1)$ .

I found this technique 
[Upper bound for zeros of holomorphic function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21437/upper-bound-for-zeros-of-holomorphic-function) , but it doesn't seem to apply to this problem.

Comment: Do you know Rouché's theorem? Compare $f$ with $z^4$.

Comment: Davide - thanks.

Comment: I considered Rouche but it does not seem to be helpful for this problem since there is so little information about $f$

Comment: I added an additional condition |f(0)|=1

Comment: I believe a solution might be to define $g: D(0,4) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ as $g(z)=f(\sqrt{z})$.   And then apply the technique here

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21437/upper-bound-for-zeros-of-holomorphic-function

to $g$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\alpha_1, \dotsc, \alpha_m$ are zeroes of $f$ on $D(0,1)$ let

$$
p(z) = 2^m\prod_{j=1}^m \frac{z-\alpha_j}{4 - \overline{\alpha}_j z}.
$$

Then $p$ is holomorphic on $D(0,2)$ and $p(\alpha_j) = 0$ for $j \in \{1, \dotsc, m\}$ and $|p(z)| = 1$ for all $z$ with $|z|=2$.  Since $f(z)/p(z)$ is holomorphic on $D(0,2)$ the maximum principle says that

$$
2^m\prod_{j=1}^m|\alpha_j|^{-1} = |f(0)/p(0)| \leq \max_{|z|=2} |f(z)/p(z)| = \max_{|z|=2} |f(z)| \leq 16.
$$

So $2^m \leq 16 \prod_{j=1}^m |\alpha_m| \leq 16$ and therefore $m \leq 4$.

Comment: Is $p$ an automorphism of $D(0,2)$?

Comment: No, but $4$ times each factor in the product is.  Lookup Blaschke product for more information.

Comment: WimC, what was your intuition to use a Blaschke product?

Comment: @jojo A famous result of Jensen (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_formula) that relates the distribution of zeroes to the growth of a function.